# Wireless always disabled (either by Ubuntu or hardware switch) - Dell L502X (12.04)

Tags: wireless

This is the most frustrating bug I've ever ran into on Ubuntu.  This was not a problem with 11.10 or even 12.04 betas.  When I boot up the wireless is always blocked, whether by a hardware switch (Fn-F2 on my laptop) or by the option in Ubuntu.  Occasionally I fool around with fn-f2 in different scenarios and I can get it working.  However, any time afterwards when I reboot the problem comes back.

I've looked into many of the other answers and tried the solutions (rfkill, rmmod, etc) to no avail.

Comment: Did you try 'rfkill unblock all'?

Comment: Yep.  There's no output and it's still disabled after.

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 1):

You said you've tried rfkill, but this worked for me,

http://www.dkvermalinux.in/2012/05/ubuntu-1204-lts-wifi-problem-hardware.html

Comment: This seems to have gotten me half way there, it's no longer being reported as soft blocked. However, I then had to completely disable networking and re-enable in order to get Wireless working again.

Answer (score 0):

After trying all the suggestions I have seen here,  I was about to give up but I happened to be installing a wifi dongle on my raspberry pi (a single board computer running linux). The instructions I found for that machine was to add the following lines to /etc/network/interfaces file.  After saving the file and reboot, my Ubuntu machine now was turning on the wifi and all is good.

after the existing lines:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

add this:

```
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan inet dhcp
   wpa-ssid "yourSSID"
   wpa-psk  "yourpassphrase"
```